# Export javascript array to a shape file

Tags: javascript, arrays, export, shapefile

I'm new to javascript and need to create a web app where a user will click a button, and the array of data will export into a shape file. After reading [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54627/esri-javascript-api-export-to-shapefile-and-csv) I know that it is possible with an ARCGIS server, but I do not have access to this.

The array in question is a stream of data similar to the following

```
var array = [
[17, 70, "mark", "let", "test", "test"],
[18, 50, "marj", "get", "test", "test"], 
ETC...]
```

I've also read about [shp-write](https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write) but I don't know where to start. Would anyone be able to give me any examples of how to do this, or pointers where to start? Thanks.

Comment: You would use `shp-write` in a browser like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jf3og4as/ Unfortunately it was last updated two years ago and is apparently using a deprecated method of JSzip.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you! This helps (but unfortunately as you said its deprecated which means doesn't work - it just produces a script error)

Comment: My comment was mostly intended to show how to start, since you said you don't know. The next step would be to contact the author of shp-write and ask them if they could maybe fix their library.

Answer (score 0):

You should just convert your data from a simple array to an array of points and an array of features, like:

```
let points = [
  [17, 70],
  [18, 50], 
  ...
];

let features = [
  {col1: "mark", col2: "let", col3: "test", col4: "test"},
  {col1: "marj", col2: "get", col3: "test", col4: "test"}, 
  ...
];
```

And then call the write function provided by `scp-write`, providing your callback function to write the resulting file (check the [examples](https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write/tree/master/example) for the callback function).

```
let scp = require('scp-write');

scp.write(features, 'POINT', points, callbackFunction);
```

Comment: This is great thank you, the array itself is imported from a database or csv file, so I can't hard code them, however I presume there is a way to take an array and split it based on [1, 2, 3, 4] where points 1,2 go to the first array, and 3,4 go into a second array, then from there doing the scp write?

Comment: Of course you can do that, just use the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on the first array to obtain the two arrays you need.